# PWM for three phase induction motor control

Tags: adc, pwm, power-electronics, induction-motor

I have been implementing control software which shall control the three phase voltage source inverter for controlling the induction motor. There are two requirements as far as the pulse width modulation (PWM):

1. carrier frequency shall be variable (due to acustic noise reduction)
2. the current control loop shall be calculated eight times per PWM period (due to minimazing transport delay  - according to the Digital Control in Power Electronics section 2.2.4, which is free available for download)

The first requirement means that the period of the pwm triangular carrier is not fixed. To be able to fullfil the second requirement I need to start A/D conversion eight times per PWM period. I am going to calculate the current control loop in the "end of A/D conversion" interrupt service routine. So I will be facing a problem that the associated interrupt service routine will not have got fixed execution period (due to the variable carrier period), which is of course problematic as far as integral time contstant of the PI controller.

Is there any other solution then interrupt service routine with variable execution period? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Calculate 8 times per PWM period at the highest frequency then naturally you calculate more times at lower frequencies and why should do so be a problem?

Comment: Andy aka, I see the problem in the fact that integral gain of digital PI controller is calculted in following manner \$ \frac{K_p\cdot T_s}{2T_i}\$, where \$T_s\$ is the execution period of the PI controller. In case the carrier frequency is variable also the \$T_s\$ is variable.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if the frequency halved and you kept the same rate of converting the signal you'd have 16 samples in one period so, just massage that into 8. It's called re-sampling.

Comment: So you suggest to take the highest carrier frequency \$f_{pwm_{max}}\$ and set the \$T_s\$ so that I have \$8\cdot T_s = T_{pwm}\$. When I have lower carrier frequency e.g. \$f_{pwm}=\frac{f_{pwm_{max}}}{2}\$ I will have 16 updates per PWM period. It means that the "end of A/D conversion" interrupt service routine will be invoked with fixed time period \$T_s\$. What I don´t understand is why I need to massage 16 samples into 8 samples in that case.

Comment: You can do what you want but you seem to be fixated on producing 8 conversions per cycle.

Comment: Doing current loop higher than PWM frequency is a nonsense, bad practice since you would saturate the PI control. It would make sense to update the current control each 8th PWM cycle and not vice versa. But 1:1 would be the maximum current control update rate.

Comment: @Marko Buršič please see the attached pdf in section 2.2.4

Comment: I don't see any pdf attachements

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not able to attach the .pdf document. But it is free for download in case you search Digital Control in Power Electronics in web browser.